# Finding CR factors of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> If $A = CR$, what are the $CR$ factors of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & A \\ 0 & A \end{pmatrix}$?

My understanding is that $C$ contains the linearly independent columns of $A$, so its column space is the same as the column space of $A$. The matrix $R$ contains coefficients of the columns of $A$ relative to the basis for the column space, and the resulting rows span the row space of $A$.

I don't know anything else about $A$, so I assume it is square and $n \times n$, but I don't believe it needs to be. It could, in principle, be the zero matrix, in which case I assume $C = R = 0$. If I try to rewrite the matrix in terms of $A = CR$, then the zero vector is certainly not part of any linearly independent set, so the only candidate for a basis for the column space of $A$ is the vector $(CR, CR)^T$, though this could be zero as well. I can try to rewrite the block matrix as:
\begin{align*} 
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & A \\ 0 & A \end{pmatrix} & = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & CR \\ 0 & CR \end{pmatrix} \\
& = \begin{pmatrix} CR \\ CR \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
I don't know how to rewrite the first matrix and separate $C$ from $R$.

Comment: By "$CR$ factors" do you mean you need to find two factors of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & A \\ 0 & A
\end{bmatrix} ?$